# OpenGL FreeImage Texture Loading Error

Tags: opengl, textures, loading, freeimage

Currently, my rendering works except for the textures rendering totally black. I am getting the error 1380, or GL_INVALID_ENUM, right after calling glTexture2D in this segment of code.  I have tried everything that I can think of, but the error will not go away.

-Calling get error right before this block of code
-Texture is in powers of 2 (128 x 128)
-Using new 24-bit photoshop .bmp

```
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT imageFormat = FreeImage_GetFileType(filename, 0);
    FIBITMAP* bmpImage = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(FreeImage_Load(imageFormat, filename));

    int width = FreeImage_GetWidth(bmpImage);
    int height = FreeImage_GetHeight(bmpImage);
    int nBPP =  FreeImage_GetBPP(bmpImage);

    if (nBPP == 32)
    {
        // Generate an ID for the texture.
        glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);

        // Bind the texture as a 2D texture.
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

        // Load the image data into the texture unit.
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)FreeImage_GetBits(bmpImage));

        if(auto temp = glGetError())
        {
            // GL_INVALID_ENUM/1380 here
        }
    }

    FreeImage_Unload(bmpImage);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return `GL_NO_ERROR` right before your `glTexImage2D()` call?

Comment: check glGet error before this code... use while (glGetError() == no_error), single statement returns only top error, but there can be more of them.

Comment: Yes, i did call glGetError() right before and it returned GL_NO_ERROR

Comment: In fact, I moved glGetError() around and it was the glTexImage2D line that is causing the error.

Comment: Considering the fact that `GL_INVALID_ENUM` has [the decimal number **1280**](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Meaning_of_errors), and there is no error code 1380, I'm concerned that you aren't reporting the error correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You say the image is 24-bits but in your code you write:

`if (nBPP == 32)`